# how can I backup kindle books out of reach of amazon?

Tags: macos, privacy, kindle

10 years ago amazon sold illegitimate copies of Orwell's 1984 and Animal Farm, and subsequently deleted them from users' devices, thereby destroying a lot of work for some. I don't think I bought anything illegitimate, but I'd still like to keep a backup of my kindle books that Amazon has no access to, just in case they decide to kill another one of the books for whatever reason. The only discussions here involve fiddling with the DRM. Do you know of another way, on a mac running Mojave?

edit @Steve Chambers: [OK button where you probably see a Download button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO4nd.png)

edit2: I don't use an actual Kindle device but the Kindle app on macOS or an iphone. Maybe this explains why downloading doesn't work.

Comment: Puzzled, as you can still get it: https://www.amazon.com/1984-Animal-Farm-George-Orwell-ebook/dp/B086T47H85/ref=pd_vtp_351_1/144-1140678-8930419?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B086T47H85&pd_rd_r=6f8805ec-2a31-4d53-a795-ed9cb8d8f206&pd_rd_w=ePFda&pd_rd_wg=Zpw8y&pf_rd_p=9f0d957d-c466-420a-817f-4adcb2657c85&pf_rd_r=Y0KZMGZQYWGCK35P3QKR&psc=1&refRID=Y0KZMGZQYWGCK35P3QKR

Comment: yes, it was just one edition back then, see NYT article ["Amazon Erases Orwell Books From Kindle"](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/07/18/technology/companies/18amazon.html). Apparently, one was only not able to redownload the book, they didnt actually erase them from the Kindle app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is easy and has nothing to do with what OS you are on

1. Sign-on to your account on Amazon and go to "Your content and devices"
2. There is a list of purchased eBooks, click the "..." button to the left of the title
3. In the "Account & Lists" menu click on "Download and transfer by USB."

The book will then download to your computer allowing you to store it any place that you like.

I do this routinely with any eBook I purchase from Amazon so I have a backup copy "just in case."

Comment: hm, thanks, I checked a few books and always get "No device is eligible for downloading the selected content" in red.

Comment: All that is "ignorable instructions" It downloads the file to your computer. Allowing you to store it elsewhere, back it up, etc. If that is the acceptable answer I would appreciate it if you would accept the answer.

Comment: No download starts for me when I click OK. I tried with Safari and Firefox. I definitely will mark this answer once I get it to work once.

Comment: Odd, after I click on the "Download and..." link, it pops up a dialog asking to choose a device (which doesn't matter, I just leave that alone) and click the yellow Download button and Safari downloads immediately.  Check Safari > Preferences > Websites > Downloads and make sure Amazon is set to Allow.

Comment: I might not be able to download the files because I always send them to the mac right after buying them. I found folders with .azw files and DRM vouchers in ~/Library/Containers/com/amazon.Kindle/Data/Library/Application Support/Kindle/My Kindle Content , the path is shown in the Preferences of the Kindle app. These .azw files are the books, I think: the free ones open in Calibre, the purchased ones give a DRM error. An archiving backup of the "My Kindle Content" folder (using Carbon Copy Cloner) should copy them to my backup drive. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: ps amazon download was set to allow. They yellow button says OK for me, not Download.